# Combine dropdown criterias to filter datatable vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bettingworkbook where I want to be able to filter my datatable based on 4 different week criteria. My filter work at the moment, so when I type in four different week numbers then I get the right results. However my datatable only visualizes one of the week numbers. Have tried to combine the week no. criteria but with no luck.

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYKXf.png)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


'Year Criteria
If Target.Address = "$C$1" Then
    If Target.Value = "All" Then
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
    Else
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    End If

'Tournament Criteria
ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
    If Target.Value = "All" Then
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3
    Else
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    End If

'Week Criteria 1
ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$3" Then
    If Target.Value = "All" Then
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
    Else
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    End If

'Week Criteria 2
ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$4" Then
    If Target.Value = "All" Then
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
    Else
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    End If

'Week Criteria 3
ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$5" Then
    If Target.Value = "All" Then
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabek1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
    Else
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    End If

'Week Criteria 4
ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$6" Then
    If Target.Value = "All" Then
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
    Else
       Worksheets("Ark1").ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue a lot of people seem to struggle with, but you can filter a range by multiple criteria by adding them to an array first like so:

```
Sub autofilter_range()
Dim filtur(1 To 4) As Variant
filtur(1) = "1"
filtur(3) = "3"
Sheet1.Range("A1:C7").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=filtur, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

This will create an array with weeks 1 to 4, then adds the values to their relevant position in the array. (1 and 3 in this case) Then it applies the autofilter with only these weeks.

However the way you autofilter currently (on worksheet change, based on recently edited cells) is very inefficient when applying multiple criteria. I suggest you swap these cells out for tickboxes, and add the values to the array based upon whether they are ticked or not:

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then filtur(1) = "1"
```

This will in one go check all the checkboxes and apply the filter upon which ones are ticket and give you a full list as required.

**EDIT**
More in depth explanation of the checkbox option:
It is best to move this code to a module instead of a worksheet function. Then call it from every checkbox like so:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
autofilter_range()
end sub
```

The code in the sub will be like so:

```
Sub autofilter_range()
Dim filtur(1 To 4) As Variant
If Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then filtur(1) = "1"
If Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then filtur(2) = "2"
If Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then filtur(3) = "3"
If Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then filtur(4) = "4"
Sheet1.Range("A1:C7").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=filtur, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

This will apply the autofilter to the weeks for each checked checkbox. As for the year, it's best to add the years to a dropdown and select from there, and have the default (blank) be all years.
Add this second autofilter after the one above:

```
Dim year as string: year = Range("whichever range your dropdown is in").value
If Not year = "" Then
    Sheet1.Range("A1:C7").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=year, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Else
    Sheet1.Range("A1:C7").AutoFilter field:=1
End If
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand this correctly, but the array you have created, would that allow me to type in any of the 52 weeks I choose? Or is it limited to 1 and 3 in the example you provided.

Also, regarding the checkbox - how would I integrate that into the code you have provided, so I will be able to choose which year and tournament I want to look into?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: For this example, the array contains slots 1, 2, 3, and 4. `filtur(1 to 4)` I use this to assign the corresponding number to the array (1=1, 2=2 etc) when this is a criteria you want to search on. In my example I selected 1 and 3, for every other one there needs to be a new line assigning the correct number to the correct slot. I'll update my answer to explore the checkbox option a bit more in a moment.

Comment: Great thank you for uploading a more detailed example.

I am still not sure how to make it possible to write a week number in one of the four week criterias and then the data table will filter on the chosen weeks.